# Pyspark Spliting List inside a list and tuple

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following

```
[('HOMICIDE', [('2017', 1)]), 
 ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', [('2017', 14), ('2016', 14), ('2015', 10), ('2013', 4), ('2014', 3)]), 
 ('ROBBERY', [('2017', 1)])]
```

How to convert to

```
[('HOMICIDE', ('2017', 1)), 
 ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2015', 10)), 
 ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2014', 3)), 
 ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2017', 14)), 
 ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2016', 14))]
```

When I tried using map its throwing as ***" AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map' "***

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('HOMICIDE', [('2017', 1)]), ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', [('2017', 14), ('2016', 14), ('2015', 10), ('2013', 4), ('2014', 3)])])
y = rdd.map(lambda x : (x[0],tuple(x[1])))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` is a method on `rdd` instead of python list, so you need to parallelize the list firstly and then you can use `flatMap` to flatten the inner lists:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('HOMICIDE', [('2017', 1)]), 
                      ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', [('2017', 14), ('2016', 14), ('2015', 10), ('2013', 4), ('2014', 3)]), 
                      ('ROBBERY', [('2017', 1)])])

rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [(x[0], y) for y in x[1]]).collect()

# [('HOMICIDE', ('2017', 1)), 
#  ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2017', 14)), 
#  ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2016', 14)), 
#  ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2015', 10)), 
#  ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2013', 4)), 
#  ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2014', 3)), 
#  ('ROBBERY', ('2017', 1))]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a list comprehension instead?

```
y = [(x[0], i) for x in rdd for i in x[1]]
```

Returns

```
[('HOMICIDE', ('2017', 1)), ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2017', 14)), ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2016', 14)), ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2015', 10)), ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2013', 4)), ('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', ('2014', 3))]
```

Comment: It worked good in python , when I used pyspark , I have to move the data to disk .... I think its my bad not mentioning as sc.parallelize in my question . Thanks @asongtoruin

Comment: @SachinSukumaran my bad! The other answer seems to have you covered anyway.